# Mysql Query get duplicate record and make virtual column if duplicate record exists

Tags: mysql

- column 1 : product_sku,
- column 2 : retailer_shop_id,
- runtime created
- column 3 : product_type

I want to get duplicate product_sku with related to retailer_shop_id if there is duplicate products_sku exist the product_type value should be "Variable" else it should be "Simple".

I think pseudocode query will be something like this:

```
SELECT product_sku,  
  IF (current_product_sku_Count > 1, 'variable', 'simple') as product_type 
FROM retailer_stock 
where retailer_shop_id = "1";
```

What condition I put in if?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can calculate the count for each product in a subquery, then in the outer query do `if` the way you did:

```
SELECT product_sku, 
  IF(sku_count > 1 , 'variable', 'simple') as product_type 
FROM
(
    SELECT product_sku, COUNT(*) AS sku_count
    FROM retailer_stock 
    where retailer_shop_id = "1";
    GROUP BY product_sku
) AS t
```